# Functions not present in Teradata

Tags: oracle11g, teradata

I want to know what are the functions which are present in Oracle 11g but missing (or has no replacement) in Teradata 14.x?

Comment: By checking the SQL manuals?

Comment: Is there any online link to it (apologies I am  new to teradata and still figuring it out).

Comment: Yo find all manuals at http://www.info.teradata.com, preferred as PDF or online. You need http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_10/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_112A/title.071.2.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know much about Oracle but I can help a little with the Teradata side.

In Teradata look at the functions in TD_SYSFNLIB and SYSLIB databases.  This is where you will probably find (or not find) most of the functions you are looking for.

There are optional Oracle-like functions that your DBA may or may not have installed in Teradata.  So the only way to know for sure what is available is to look.

In teradata you could also query DBC.TablesV where Tablekind is F, A or R.  The decode for TableKind is:

- T Data Table
- V View
- M Macro
- J Journal Table
- I Join Index Table
- P Stored Procedure
- G Trigger
- F Scalar UDF
- A Aggregate UDF
- N Hash Index Table
- U User-defined Data Type
- H Instance or Constructor Method
- E External Stored Procedure
- R Table Function
- X Authorization

There are probably also other system views in DBC where you can query this info.